# Imputation process before LDA

Tags: r, data-imputation, caret, discriminant-analysis, mice

I want to perform LDA in my cohort which is based on 140 inviduals distributed according in 3 groups. These individuals have undergone an analysis of 50 variables (gene expression). So my dataset is 137x51 (1 categorical variable + 50 numerical variables)

I want to perform LDA and see how the individuals behave using the multiple predictors (in my case a set of genes). However I am not sure how to deal with missing values in the dataset, and which method fits better to the LDA. I lie my doubts in here to see if somebody has experience in this topic:

The mice package has multiple approaches to do it with "pmm", "norm" or whatever. From my point of view, the missing values due to non amplification molecular process are missing completely at random, but seems that this consideration introduces a bias. So they could be treated as missing at random and perform multiple imputation. The thing is, should I construct blocks with the mice package, according to the genes and their family belonging, or should I leave the default option and let the imputation work.

My data adjusts to normal distribution

Thanks in advance